# Doctrine, How to get only one row in inner join?

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Suppose I have classes like below:

```
class user 
{
     first name
     last name
}

class record
{         
}

class history 
{
    timestamp
    action        
}
```

A user can have many history for one record. Bassically user has many-to-many relation to record through history.

Let's say:

```
User-1 approved Record-1 at 2012-06-14 11:18:59     
User-1 updated  Record-1 at 2012-06-13 11:18:59
User-1 denied   Record-1 at 2012-06-12 11:18:59
User-1 created  Record-1 at 2012-06-11 11:18:59
```

The thing is the last `action` in history shows the `status` of the record. I would like to write a query in `doctrine` with `createQueryBuilder` that retrieve all `users` and the latest action. For example in the scenario above, should return `Record-1` as `approved`, but no other record.

Another question is how to `SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.latest.action IS approved`. The query is to just make it clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be a time where you want to duplicate information to vastly simplify your queries. Instead of requiring several complicated joins, or a correlated subquery, it might be worth it to simply add a "lastest_action" field to User, and update it whenever a user takes an action. You run the risk of having inconsistent data in your DB if you don't update everything correctly, but you'll be running faster and simpler queries to get this information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had the solution you mentioned above in mind, but I am really curious about what would be the best practice for these kind of relations and not to worry about integrity.